# Use generating functions to find the number of partitions of $n>1$ that have an odd number of even parts $k=1,...,10$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Here are some examples where we find $f(n)$ - the number of partitions that satisfy our condition:

$\boldsymbol{2} = (1+1) \rightarrow \boldsymbol{f(2)=0} $

$\boldsymbol{3} = (1+1+1) = \boldsymbol{(1+2)} \rightarrow \boldsymbol{f(3)=1} $ (we have one '2' in (1+2), which satisfies the "odd number of even parts" condition)

$\boldsymbol{4} = (1+1+1+1) = \boldsymbol{(1+1+2)} = (2+2) = (1+3) \rightarrow \boldsymbol{f(4)=1} $

$\boldsymbol{5} = (1+1+1+1+1) = \boldsymbol{(1+1+1+2)} = (1+2+2) = (1+1+3) = \boldsymbol{(1+4)} \rightarrow \boldsymbol{f(5)=2} $

$\boldsymbol{6} = (1+1+1+1+1+1) = \boldsymbol{(1+1+1+1+2)} = (1+1+2+2) = \boldsymbol{(2+2+2)} = (1+1+1+3) = (3+3) = \boldsymbol{(1+2+3)} = \boldsymbol{(1+1+4)} = (2+4) = (1+5)\rightarrow \boldsymbol{f(6)=4} $

Now how can we do this for any number $n$, keeping in mind that all parts should be in range $1,...,10$?

Comment: f(5)=3, isn't it? Or is there a reason leaving (2+3) out?

Answer (score 1):

The counts you look for is http://oeis.org/A000701, where you can find a generating function.
Let P(n) be the count of partitions of n, and g(n) the coefficient of x^n in
f(x)= $\prod _{k=0}^{\infty } \left(x^{2 k+1}+1\right)$
then you want (P(n)- g(n) )/2.

Comment: Those numbers are without the restriction that the parts be not greater than 10.

Answer (score 1):

The generating function in the oeis entry provided by Wouter M. can be modified.

For all the parts to be in $1,2,\ldots ,10$, the g.f. is:

$\displaystyle
P(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\prod_{i=1}^{5}\dfrac{1-x^{2\, i}}{1+x^{2\, i}}\right)\left(\prod_{j=1}^{10}\dfrac{1}{1-x^i}\right)
$

If the partion is to have more than one part, subtract that by $\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}$

Comment: A more complex situation arises when counting the partitions of n in which the even parts are as well odd in number and have sizes not greater than 10. Difference is that the odd parts are now allowed to have any size. This produces for n=1 .. 20: 0,1,1,2,3,5,7,10,14,20,27,36,48,64,83,108,139,179,227,287  and I can't get a GF for this one!

Comment: I too did not get a g.f. for that.